# Microsoft access - Percentage Complete

Tags: ms-access

Basically i would like to create a form/Report that shows a user what percentage of a job is complete (i have done that) but from the percentage, work out how much of the "quote" is completed (e.g. Quote = £100..... Percentage = 50% complete.... so the job would now be at £50 complete.

The next stage would then be working out the total of ALL the quotes (e.g. £100,000) and gathering The completion money count (e.g. £40,000, as some job may have different percentages complete) i can then compare the expected amount with the dates they are due by and what the actual completion amount is, at the moment.

I'm not saying its an easy or hard task to do, but if someone were willing to help that would be excellent.

Comment: See this. It's for Excel but with very little effort you can make it work in ms-access: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/progress-indicator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the percentage calculated, say 50% which is 0.5, all you need is to multiply:

```
QuoteCompleted = QuoteTotal * CalculatedPercentage
```

or, as a *ControlSource*:

```
=[Quote]*[TextboxHoldingCalculatedPercentage]
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, i have not calculated the percentages yet, all i have is rows of percentages for job. i now need to guery the jobs/quotes then work out the average percentage for eache job. as well as the above problem of working out the quote (£) compared to the percentage of completion

Comment: Then, I guess, you need to sum the _quotes_ and sum the _quotes completed_ and calculate the percentage of completion.

Comment: i have used this as a formula "[Actaul Quote]*[Completion]/100" it is for some reason calculating 50% as 0.5, how do i change this to 50?

Comment: 50% _is_ 0.5. So, you need to set the Format property of the textbox to: Percent.